# WooCommerce and WordPress REST API for User Registration and Login

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm currently exploring the WooCommerce REST API as I plan to use WordPress as a Headless CMS. However, I'm facing confusion regarding user registration and login through the API. Specifically, I'm unsure about the endpoints or API routes used for creating, registering, and logging in users.

Could someone provide guidance on the appropriate endpoints or API methods for managing user-related operations in WooCommerce and WordPress?

Answer (score -1):

For endpoints related to WooCommerce customers take a look at the [customers section of the official WooCommerce API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#customers).

For endpoints related to WordPress users take a look at the [users section of the official WordPress API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/).